# "curl" downloads .zip file as ASCII text (zipfile is not corrupted!)

Tags: linux, rhel, curl, zip

I want to download package from Artifactory. If I download it manually from Artifactory UI, and transfer that file to Linux server (RHEL 8) I can see that file is in proper ZIP format:

```
file arena-web.zip
arena-web.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

If I try to download it using the CURL from the same Linux server, I get the file as ASCII text which I cannot unzip of course (and that is the my main issue)

```
file arena-web.zip
arena-web.zip: ASCII text
```

curl command which I used:

```
 curl -u "user:pass" -O https://artifactory_my_domain/packages/arena-web.zip
```

I tried with `-L` and `-o` options as well.

Is this some sort of a bug or what can be the issue?

Update - content of the "text file version":

```
{
  "repo" : "uueaw-generic-snapshot-local",
  "path" : "/packages/arena-web.zip",
  "created" : "2022-01-13T13:53:49.152Z",
  "createdBy" : "svcacct",
  "lastModified" : "2022-01-13T13:53:48.973Z",
  "modifiedBy" : "svcacct",
  "lastUpdated" : "2022-01-13T13:53:49.153Z",
  "downloadUri" : "https://artifactory_mydomain/artifactory/uueaw-generic-snapshot-local/packages/arena-web.zip",
  "mimeType" : "application/zip",
  "size" : "5412051",
  "checksums" : {
    "sha1" : "6e5069ee60b1977ad13ddf45a30c12c5fd1d8719",
    "md5" : "46fa87adefe864b13bb2216801d246b1",
    "sha256" : "a08361f71ec483044f675af07ff8ca214dc2f17a9510c2a626ed57e04670cbfb"
  },
  "originalChecksums" : {
    "sha1" : "6e5069ee60b1977ad13ddf45a30c12c5fd1d8719",
    "md5" : "46fa87adefe864b13bb2216801d246b1",
    "sha256" : "a08361f71ec483044f675af07ff8ca214dc2f17a9510c2a626ed57e04670cbfb"
  },
  "uri" : "https://artifactory_my_domain/artifactory/api/storage/uueaw-generic-snapshot-local/packages/arena-web.zip"
}
```

Comment: What are the contents of the text file version? That should give a clue as to what the issue is.

Comment: Chances are that the server wants to set a cookie or execute some javascript, and what you're getting is some HTML intended to inform a human of what to do. Look at the content of the file.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson and Gilless I updated the question with the content.
Can you conclude something based on this? Thanks a lot

Comment: It looks as if what you want to get is actually what's in the value of the top-level `uri` (or `downloadUri`) key.

Comment: ah, that seems to be some kind of download descriptor, not what you originally wanted to download. Try jsut downloading the `downloadUri` URI.

Comment: also, after downloading, run `sha256sum` on the file, and check whether it matches `sha256`.

Comment: Thanks! it was wrong URI. Now the zip file is correct! Marcus how I can run `sha256sum` to check with the `sha256` value?

Answer (score 0):

`file` is also just human; it might simply be wrong. (it uses heuristics, nothing can guarantee that not some other file format gets wrongly interpreted)

If not:

A zipfile can perfectly well start with something that is valid ASCII text; that's a result of the lenient definition of the file format.

This leads to the existence of so-called file-format *polyglots*, i.e. files that are valid as multiple files. A common example is [The International Journal of PoC||GTFO](https://www.sultanik.com/pocorgtfo/), whose PDF files usually double as valid ZIP, windows execuatble, as bootable disk image, game console ROM image, music file, and combinations of these.

For more examples of Polyglots, Ange Albertini has excellent [talks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdCs6bPM4is) on the subject, and his [github account](https://github.com/corkami/pocs/tree/master/zip) harbors a lot of examples for zip polyglots and variants; [this one](https://github.com/corkami/pocs/tree/master/poly/CorkaMIX) is a ZIP (a JAR, which is ZIP with a Java .class inside), that's also a Python script (so, starts with ASCII text), a Windows Executable, and  a PDF. Why? Because.

Comment: Thanks but this does not resolve my issue. I simply cannot unzip that zip file which is the main reason why I am generating this issue. I mentioned that in my question - I cannot unzip that file if that is the case - so what is the solution??? Unzip output:
`Archive:arena-web
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of arena-web.zip`